# AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'btn_click'

Tags: python, pyqt, attributeerror

I keep getting this error when trying to call the button click function. I tried the other answers about attribute errors but couldn't figure out what I have done wrong. I am trying to grab the text in a qlineedit and store that in variable training_epochs then call a function Train. Thanks in advance.
My code below:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(573, 483)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.Epochs = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Epochs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 120, 113, 20))
        self.Epochs.setObjectName("Epochs")

        def btn_click(self):
            training_epochs=self.Epochs.text()
            Train(training_epochs)
            return

        self.TrainNeuralNetwork = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.TrainNeuralNetwork.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 90, 141, 23))
        self.TrainNeuralNetwork.setObjectName("TrainNeuralNetwork")
        self.TrainNeuralNetwork.clicked.connect(self.btn_click) #error occurs here

        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 240, 256, 192))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 573, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Epochs"))
        self.TrainNeuralNetwork.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Train Neural Network"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: delete 1 tab of the btn_click function, it must be at the same level of setupUi().

Comment: Thanks it worked great!